# Check MCMC stationarity and convergence before or after thinning?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

```
library(BRugs)
library(coda)
...
output = BRugsFit("model.bug", data, inits, numChains = 1, nThin = 5, 
         seed=6, parametersToSave, nBurnin = 9, nIter = 50,coda = T,digits = 5)

# computes the effective sample sizes.
effectiveSize(output)

HPDinterval(output,prob=.9)

# diagnostics 
geweke.diag(output)
raftery.diag(output)
gelman.diag(output)
```

`output` will contains the iterations after removing burn-in period (here it is 9) and thinning (here 5). So there are 50/5=10 iterations in `output`.

I wonder whether to check the diagnostics (geweke, raftery, gelman, and possibly more) before or after removing burn-in and/or thinning?

Thanks!